# Better compression using DirextX.Filters.VideoCompressor

Tags: vb.net, directx, directshow

I am working with a realtime video recorder, however when I am recording videos, the size of the video is really HUGE! It's like 50MBps.
Im using libraries `DirectX` and `DirectShowLib`

I used the following VideoCompressor

```
capture.VideoCompressor = Filters.VideoCompressors(0)
```

Not the video is like 5MBps, but still this is very huge!

The name of the Compressor on that index is DV Video Encoder.
And here are the list of video encoders starting from 0

```
DV Video Encoder
ffdshow video encoder
MJPEG Compressor
MSScreen 9 encoder DMO
UtVideo Pro YUV422 10bit DMO
UtVideo RGB DMO
UtVideo RGBA DMO
UtVideo YUV420 BT.601 DMO
UtVideo YUV420 BT.709 DMO
UtVideo YUV422 BT.601 DMO
UtVideo YUV422 BT.709 DMO
WMVideo8 Encoder DMO
WMVideo9 Encoder DMO
```

But unfortunately DV Video Encoder with the index of 0 only works with the Above code, or else if I change to Filers.VideoCompressors(1) which is ffdshow video encoder, it will give me an error

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COMP component.
```

Any chance of compressing it effectively? Or should I use ffmpeg ? If so then how could I compress ffmpeg with the video running?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would like to mention that ffdshow video encoder is essentially a ffmpeg adopted for direct show. However it requires additional configuration (like selecting one of available codecs and configuring it) and I'm not sure that it is possible (or reasonable) to use it through vb.net API (which is rather limited if I remember correctly). UtVideo YUV422 BT.601 and UtVideo YUV422 BT.709 would be a good choice for SD and HD video encoding. They are rather fast and produce lossless video with reasonable compression which may later be compressed using slow, but high compression codecs, such as h264 or h265. You can probably use ffmpeg as well as it [does support direct show sources as inputs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow).

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you want to use certain specific video encoding, such as especially H.264 or Windows Media Video, because the this stipulates further integration options (specific file format or streaming integration etc). Then you use specific codec which you know to be good for your purpose (fast enough or has specific encoding options that are mandatory etc). That is, `Filters.VideoCompressors` collection is not exactly a rich collection of your choices but rather an accessor to pick a codec you already know and look for.

Sadly, DirectShow stock codec offering is not good. There are reasons for it, including that DirectShow itself is older than most popular codecs, and then licensing issues prevented from making the good codecs available right from the start. Later, DirectShow was already at retirement age and H.264 encoder was offered through newer API only.

So your steps here are the following (assuming you are staying with `DirectShowLib`):

1. Understand what video encoding you are going to use
2. If you want to stay with stock encoders, your likely option is WMVideo9 Encoder DMO and Windows Media Video in general
3. Otherwise you are to identify codec of your interest, an H.264 codec as a likely option, understand what it takes to make it available via DirectShow
4. Use the collection to locate the codec of your interest, per written above, instantiate the codec from there and include in your DirectShow pipeline